# Russian equivalent of expression "you know"

Tags: выражения, idioms, слова-паразиты

Sometimes I feel the need to fill a gap, while conversing, with something that in English would be filled with "you know" in the sense described by [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/you+know):

> Used parenthetically in conversation, as to fill pauses or educe the listener's agreement or sympathy: *Please try to be, you know, a little quieter*

In case people are used to say something analogue in Russian, which expression can be used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those expressions are called "fillers".

Russian, as most languages, has many of them: *как бы, типа, знаешь, так сказать* etc:

They usually don't need to be translated verbatim:

> - Постарайся вести себя, ну, знаешь, потише
> - Постарайся вести себя как бы потише
> - Постарайся вести себя, типа, потише
> - Постарайся вести себя, так сказать, потише

are all valid.

In Russian linguistics, those are called "parasitic words" (*слова-паразиты*)

Comment: у меня иногда подозрение, что не в русской лингвистике они так называются, а в среде учительниц русского языка)))

Comment: И правильно называются =) Очень точное определение, пусть и неофициальное. Привычка "типкать" и "экать" в паузах между словами прилепляется очень прочно =)

Comment: @petajamaja, ну я б всё-таки слова вроде "знаешь, послушай" не стал бы в одну кучу с эканьем. Они иногда привносят определённый оттенок теплоты в беседу))

Comment: @petajamaja They are not just "parasitic words", they are also called ["discursive words"](http://postnauka.ru/faq/8572).

Comment: @Artemix - Wow, such a nice article! thanks =)

Comment: That was a fantastic article! By the way, I believe we call these "discourse words" in English.

Comment: Just to add that each of the aforementioned words carries a different flavour and would be used in slightly difference circumstances: "типа" is less cultured, more suited to a street youth, while "так сказать" is more cultured and old-timey.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some more possibilities:

- Слышишь, веди себя потише.
- Видишь ли, надо себя вести потише.
- Веди себя, понимаешь, потише.

Comment: +1 for понимаешь )))

Answer (score 4):

"**знаешь ли**"

Знаешь ли, дорогой, веди себя потише.

Comment: so, if I speak with some woman, "дорогая". Wouldn't I need to be very close to the person to say that?

Comment: @c.p. no. i would say, it is a kind of sarcasm, like addressing somebody "уважаемый".

Comment: @c.p. the "знаешь ли", especially the "ли" makes it less polite, if you want to be more polite you better not to use it. If you are addressing a close person, you can say "знаешь" or "знаешь что".

Comment: "знаешь ли" would implyes continuation like "знаешь ли, дорогой, веди себя потише, а то ведь я могу и по морде надавать".

Comment: @Anixx, 100% agree, but such a funny example =)

Answer (score 0):

Russian language has many lexical constructions which can be considered as "fillers".

Some of them:

Вводные слова (introductory words)

> ***видишь ли***, здесь все не так просто - ***you see***, everything is not so simple here

Частицы (co-words making sentence more expressive)

> вы ***бы*** залатили за аренду квартиры - ***would*** you pay for renting an apartment

Answer (score -1):

try please: можете, пожалуйста, вести себя потише?

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! It's a *very* succinct answer, we usually prefere more elaborated ones. As it stands, it's at risk to be downvoted and eventually removed. Also, your translation seem to fit for the sentence, but I'm not sure whether  *пожалуйста* can be translated as "you know" as a general rule. Could you elaborate?