# Для чего нужны "слова-паразиты" - "ну", "ведь", "же", "вот"?

Tags: лексикон, выражения, слова-паразиты

В русском языке есть много так называемых "слов-паразитов", которые можно убрать из текста, причем сам текст от этого не пострадает. Более того - текст (или устная речь) станет грамотнее, "чище".

Например, словами-паразитами называют частицы "же", "ведь", "ну", "вот"; слова и выражения "кстати", "так вот", "вообще",

Нужны ли эти слова в русском языке? Если единственная функция этих слов - "заполнение времени", то почему слов-паразитов так много? Неужели нельзя обойтись только словом "э" или "ну"?

Comment: Добавлю список "стоп-слов" или слов-паразитов, которые приводил в пример Максим Ильяхов на своём курсе - http://vsevolodustinov.ru/blog/2012/07/13/1/#.UZzMiEpMenB В конспекте много полезного о том, как сократить текст и сделать его понятнее. Автор курса утверждает, что не только в информационном стиле, но и в художественной литературе эти слова не стоит употреблять, так как они действительно засоряют текст.

Comment: @CleverMasha Если автору нужно показать запинающегося в своей речи героя ему придется использовать слова-паразиты.

Comment: Да, согласна с вами. Еще о дискурсивных словах есть интересное видео с доктором филологических наук Института языкознания РАН: http://postnauka.ru/video/2961

Comment: @CleverMasha Там справа под видео есть кнопка-сылочка на текст этого видео. Мой ответ внизу это укороченная его версия.

Comment: Quite a strange question. Let's compare to English words-parasites f.e. "you know", "listen", "well" - of course those are necessary words. Only inappropriate usage of them (too often, or in inappropriate place) makes them parasites. So "parasitism" of words only exists in context of a phrase. Not that the word itself always is a parasite.

Comment: @farfareast This was posted as kind-of-responce to [Russian equivalent of expression “you know”](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/russian-equivalent-of-expression-you-know), where all such words were called "parasite".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Википедия пишет о [словах-паразитах](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B) следующее:

> «Слова-паразиты» — лингвистическое явление, выраженное в употреблении лишних и бессмысленных в данном контексте слов вроде «типа», «например», «как бы», «это самое», «собственно», «ну..», «так сказать», «вот», «как сказать», «в общем-то», «понимаешь», «а именно», «на этом» и других. Синтаксически большинство «слов-паразитов» являются вводными словами.

Но есть у этих слов и другая роль - они могут использоваться для обеспечения связности текста и выступают в этом случае в роли [дискурсивных слов](http://postnauka.ru/faq/8572).

Дискурсивные слова – это сравнительно новая область лингвистики. Так в узком смысле называют особую группу слов: не "основное ядро", несущее главную нагрузку в передаче смыслового задания, а "служебные" слова, отражающие то, как говорящий работает над текстом, что он думает: трудно ему или легко, как он воспринимает адресата, много или мало, по его мнению, знает адресат, раздражает он говорящего или, наоборот, нравится ему. Эти слова помечают разные этапы создания текста.

> Например, «слушай меня внимательно, сейчас будет самое важное» – в этом значении мы часто употребляем единицу **так вот**. Или, например: «А сейчас я делаю отступление, это менее важно, имейте в виду, но скоро я вернусь к важному». Этот смысла может скрываться за коротким **кстати**.

Кроме того, дискурсивные слова часто выражают разное отношение к адресату. Хорошо ли я знаю его, близко ли он мне знаком. Не всякому человеку скажешь *ведь*, или *вот*, или *ка* (как в *сделай-ка*) – эта частица тоже дискурсивное слово, которое свидетельствует об особом отношении между говорящим и адресатом, скорее всего, об их близком знакомстве или неформальных отношениях.

> "Ты **ведь** туда уже ходил" – попробуйте перевести его на какой-то другой язык. Если попытаться это сделать, то приблизительно получится: «ты знаешь и я знаю, что ты туда ходил, но, наверное, ты об этом забыл, и я хочу тебе напомнить об этом, при этом я удивляюсь, потому что я считаю, что ты об этом должен бы был помнить». В этом слове помещается очень сложное и очень эмоциональное значение – напоминание говорящего адресату, что тот должен извлечь из своей памяти нечто очевидное, но при этом потерянное.
>
> У слова **ну** тоже очень сложный комплекс значений. Оно возникает, как правило, в начале реплики и свидетельствует о том, что говорящий раздумывает, не знает точно, что ответить, и пытается выиграть время, чтобы выбрать то, что кажется ему оптимальным.

Дискурсивные слова принадлежат не только к разговорной речи, по крайней мере для русского языка это не так. Даже в русских научных статьях их очень много: *таким образом, очевидно, тем не менее, в целом*, и т.д., и т.п.

Дискурсивные слова не связаны также со степенью литературной обработанности, «развитости» языка: они есть и в литературных языках с давней традицией, и в малых, в бесписьменных языках. А связано их присутствие, скорее всего, с тем, насколько в данном языке – и в данной культуре – важно внимание к информации, получаемой только при межличностном общении (особенно когда собеседники хорошо знают друг друга).

Интересно что дискурсивных слов было очень много в древнегреческом языке. Не всегда было понятно как их переводить, поэтому часто переводчики их просто пропускали. Видимо, греческий текст – в том числе и научный – вырастал непосредственно из диалога, ведь дискурсивных слов много там, где есть установка на постоянное межличностное взаимодействие.

Comment: Please refrain from excessive citing.

Comment: @Quassnoi I have spent at least 30 minutes trying to compact this answer as much as possible. I'm sorry for excessive citing, but I think this information is worth spreading on RL&U.

Comment: @Quassnoi I've never seen somebody compain about too much citing before

Comment: @PeterOlson: it just seemed to me that the whole post is a copy-paste, however, the op did explain himself.

Comment: Another article on "parasytes": [Почему мы используем слова-паразиты?](http://postnauka.ru/faq/21777). "Для лингвистов наблюдение за «словами-паразитами» в живой речи даёт бесценный материал: фактически эти слова открывают доступ в «лабораторию говорящего», позволяя обнаружить болевые точки в процессе порождения неподготовленной речи и понять, какими способами преодолеваются речевые затруднения."